# Resizing Image and Content on Card

Tags: css, materialize

I am experimenting with some effects using the materializecss framework.
I am attempting to resize the image and the content on card when user hovers over it, but cannot seem to crack it.

```css
.card:hover .card-image {
    height: 50%;
}

.card:hover .card-content {
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m7">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/nightlife/">
                <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
               <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I just cannot get this to work.
I've applied height changes to img, elements within card-content, card class etc but nothing seems to give.

Comment: Can you attach a snap of what you are trying to achieve in question or please elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.card:hover .card-image img {
    width: 50%;
}
```

height is tricky with a scrolling page, and you probably want to hit the image, not the div unless you also set `ovrflow: hidden` if you are trying to crop the image?  With the .card.content not sure what you are trying to achieve.. perhaps `font-size: 50%`?

height and width percentages are relative to the parent element, not the element to which the styles are being applied.. so an image with a width of 50% is 50% the width of its parent, not the source file...if my recollection is correct.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rLknLvdm/)**

Comment: This resizes the whole card rather then sections of it. I want the card size to stay the same just content within it to be reshuffled

Comment: reshuffled? Perhaps you could elaborate re what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Resize the card-image and card-content. Card size stays the same to retain responsivenes but image and content get resized further on hover.